# Why am I getting this error AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In PyCharm when I execute my code its throwing this error. Is this something inside my code here or is it from my CRUD file?  Hoping I just made a typo that sticks out.

I am reading the data from a database, putting it into a dataframe and then into a dictionary.

Here is the full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\***\***\Desktop\****\Original\FinalProject.py", line 48, in <module>
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in shelter.read({}).columns]
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'columns'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```python
> import dash_core_components as dcc
> import dash_html_components as html
> import dash_table
> import pandas as pd
> from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
> from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
> 
> from AnimalShelter_CRUD import AnimalShelter
> 
> WATER_RESCUE_FILTER = {
> >     '$or': [{"breed": "Labrador Retriever Mix"}, {"breed": "Chesapeake Bay Retriever"}, {"breed": "Newfoundland"}],
>     "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks": {'$gt': 26, '$lt': 156}, "sex_upon_outcome": "Intact Female"}
> 
> MOUNTAIN_RESCUE_FILTER = {
>     '$or': [{"breed": "German Shepherd"}, {"breed": "Alaskan Malamute"}, {"breed": "Old English Sheepdog"},
>             {"breed": "Siberian Husky"}, {"breed": "Rottweiler"}], "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks": {'$gt': 26, '$lt': 156},
>     "sex_upon_outcome": "Intact Male"}
> 
> DISASTER_RESCUE_FILTER = {
>     '$or': [{"breed": "German Shepherd"}, {"breed": "Doberman Pinscher"}, {"breed": "Golden Retriever"},
>             {"breed": "Bloodhound"}, {"breed": "Rottweiler"}], "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks": {'$gt': 20, '$lt': 300},
>     "sex_upon_outcome": "Intact Male"}
> 
> app = JupyterDash('SimpleExample')
> 
> username = "myUserAdmins2"
> password = "123456"
> shelter = AnimalShelter(username, password)
> 
> external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
> 
> app.layout = html.Div([
> dcc.RadioItems(
> id='rd',
> options=[
>             {'label': 'Water Rescue', 'value': 'Water Rescue'},
>             {'label': 'Mountain', 'value': 'Mountain or Wilderness Rescue'},
>             {'label': 'Disaster Rescue ', 'value': 'Disaster Rescue or Individual Tracking'},
>             {'label': 'Reset', 'value': 'Reset'}
>         ],
> value='Water Rescue',
> labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
>     ),
> html.Hr(),
> html.Div(id='dd-output-container', children=[
> dash_table.DataTable(
> id='datatable-id',
> columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in shelter.read({}).columns]
>         )
>     ]),
> html.Hr(),
> html.Div(id='map-id'),
> html.Hr(),
> html.Div(id='graph-id')
> ])
> 
> 
> def filter_data(value):
> if value == 'Water Rescue':
> return shelter.read(WATER_RESCUE_FILTER)
> elif value == 'Mountain or Wilderness Rescue':
> return shelter.read(MOUNTAIN_RESCUE_FILTER)
> elif value == 'Disaster Rescue or Individual Tracking':
> return shelter.read(DISASTER_RESCUE_FILTER)
> else:
> return shelter.read({})
> 
> 
> def update_table(data):
> return [
> dash_table.DataTable(
> id='datatable-id',
> columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in data.columns],
> data=data.to_dict('records'),
> editable=True,
> style_cell={'textAlign': 'left'},
> style_cell_conditional=[{'if': {'column_id': s}, 'textAlign': 'left'} for s in
> ['animal_type', 'color', 'breed', 'animal_id']],
> style_data_conditional=[{'if': {'row_index': 'odd'}, 'backgroundColor': 'rgb(0, 128, 0)'}],
> style_header={'backgroundColor': 'rgb(0, 238, 0)', 'fontWeight': 'bold'},
> filter_action="native",
> sort_action="native",
> sort_mode="multi",
> column_selectable="single",
> row_selectable="multi",
> row_deletable=True,
> selected_columns=[],
> selected_rows=[],
> page_action="native",
> page_current=0,
> page_size=10,
>         )
>     ]
> 
> 
> @app.callback(
> Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
> [Input('rd', 'value')]
> )
> def update_output(value):
> try:
> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(filter_data(value))
> return update_table(df)
> except Exception as e:
> return html.Div(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", style={'color': 'red'})
> 
> 
> if __name__ == '__main__':
> app.run_server(mode='jupyterlab', port=8090, dev_tools_ui=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=True, threaded=True)
```

My question is where am I missing this attribute for columns?

shelter is pulling from my AnimalShelter_CRUD file here.

```
# Example Python Code to Insert a Document
from pymongo import MongoClient


class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to
        # access the MongoDB databases and collections.
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:27017/AAC' % (username, password))
        self.database = self.client['AAC']

    # Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            self.database.animals.insert_one(data)  # data should be dictionary
            print("++++++++++++++++++ animal created successifully+++++++++++++++")
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")

    # THIS IS A READ METHOD
    def read(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            data = self.database.animals.find(data, {"_id": False})  # data should be dictionary
            return data
        else:
            raise Exception("nothing to read, hint is empty")

    # this method will receive a dictionary, find all items that match the dictionary
    # values and delete them
    def delete(self, _data):
        if _data is not None:
            data = self.read(_data)  # check if animal exists
            if data is None:
                print("Animal not found")
                return
            # if found delete the animal or animals
            self.database.animals.delete_many(_data)  # data should be dictionary
            data = self.read(_data)  # confirm if animal was deleted
            return data
        else:
            raise Exception("nothing to read, hint is empty")

    # this method update using the id of the collection, one can also update using any key
    def update(self, _keys, _data):
        if _data is not None and _keys is not None:
            self.database.animals.update_many(_keys, {'$set': _data})  # _keys will check for the doc to update
            data = self.read(_data)
            return data
        else:
            raise Exception("please enter both key and data to modify the collection")
```

Comment: I see 2 places that refer to that attribute: `shelter.read({}).columns` and `data.columns`.  It looks like data comes from `pd.DataFrame.from_records(filter_data(value))`. Where does `shelter` come from?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @Joe shelter = AnimalShelter.  Which is the AnimalShelter_CRUD file.  I will add the AnimalShelter_CRUD file below my code above.

Comment: _`data = self.database.animals.find(data, {"_id": False})  # data should be dictionary`_  No, it won't be a dictionary.